# prepareForSegue displaying blank view

Tags: objective-c, segue, viewcontroller

I am trying to create a simple app where the user takes a picture, the user gets prompted to a preview of the taken picture(PreviewController) and then the user goes to another view(FrameController) to select a frame for the picture.

My prepareForSegue looks like this

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pushToPreview"])
 {

    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.collectionView indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    PreviewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [indexPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    destViewController.passFrameLabel = [self.frameImages[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.collectionView deselectItemAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
 }
}
```

After going back to the PreviewController, The previously taken picture is gone and also xcode is displaying a blank screen without displaying the frame selected by the user.

After debugging, both self.frameImages and self.CollectionViewhave their value inside.

What I am missing?
Any help will be highly appreciated

viewDidLoad now looks like this

> self.frameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.passFrameLabel];

Now the frame selected by the user do appears BUT the preview pictures is still wiped and not appearing after coming back from the TemplateController

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

1. Select the segue in storyboard.
   [image]
2. Set the segue identifier.
   [image]

Compile and run. Enjoy :)

Comment: It is set now as modal. If I set as Push then the application terminates.

Comment: It is applicable for both types whether you have modal or push. You should name it.

Comment: The frame appears but the picture taken at the beginning is wiped by xcode.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you?

Comment: *being. I am using this prepareForSegue to go back to a view controller where there is supposed to be a UIImage showing a preview of a picture already taken. That picture disappears.

Comment: Please add some code, so that i can get some idea what was happening there.

Comment: Hi, please write your following code in viewDidAppear: method. self.frameImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.passFrameLabel];

Comment: I tried that and it happens the same thing. The frame selected does appear but the first picture is not appearing.
1: Take Picture (MainController)
2: Picture is displayed (PreviewController)
3: Tap Template button which takes the user to the Template Controller(TemplateController)
4: Tap on template or frame(these are displayed in a collection view) and return to PreviewController
5: Frame appears in PreviewController but picture from step #2 is gone......